# Cannot call jqGrid functions using . operator

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I cannot call jqgrid using the . operator as given in the examples:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").editGridRow( "new", options );
```

I get the following error:

`jQuery("#grid_id").editGridRow is not a function`

Instead I always have to make a call in the following way:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid("editGridRow", "new", options );
```

I don't have any problems with the latter approach - I am curious why the former does not work for me, when most examples and tutorials using the former approach

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you used the following code

```
jQuery.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
```

somewhere in you program either directly or indirectly (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#configuring_jqgrid_to_use_only_the_new_api)). The code prohibit the usage of "old style" API.

By the way if you prefer the usage of the "old style" API because of [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) support in the Visual Studio you can use the "new style" API in a little other form:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid.editGridRow ("new", options);
```

instead of

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid ("editGridRow", "new", options);
```

In the case there are no conflicts with another jQuery Plug-Ins which described Nick Craver, but the [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) will continue work:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: yup - that is absolutely correct! thanks a ton - wish i could vote this up +10

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way the plugin designers chose to do it.  The alternative is to have all of their methods on `$.fn` (present on the prototype, so on *every* jQuery object), which has a few issues:

- Now there are lots of methods defined on every object
- Potential for conflict, what if they wanted an already taken jQuery method, or one jQuery adds later?

[The list of methods jqGrid has isn't short](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods), so this is a way for them to keep it under control and compartmentalized.  Also, this isn't unique to jqGrid...for example the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) theming it accepts, [all of the widgets in that library](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) follow the same convention.

Comment: but did they change this recently? because the documentation say this is valid: jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('method', parameter1,...parameterN ); -- http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods